# docker-entrypoint.sh: executable file not found in $PATH

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-entrypoint

I was able to build a successful image out of the Dockerfile below but I failed to run the image and I get the error below even though I have copied the entrypoint.sh to the right location. Any pointers to fix this would be great.

**Error: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "docker-entrypoint.sh": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.**

```
ENV NODE_VERSION 12.22.6

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/   
ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint.sh"]

CMD [ "node" ]
```

the docker-entrypoint.sh looks like below:

```
#!/bin/sh
set -e

if [ "${1#-}" != "${1}" ] || [ -z "$(command -v "${1}")" ]; then
  set -- node "$@"
fi

exec "$@"
```

Comment: Can you reduce this example to a [mcve]?  For example, is the list of GPG key IDs necessary to demonstrate the permission error?  Have you verified that the entrypoint script is executable, has a correct `#!` "shebang" line at the beginning, and has Unix line endings if you're on a Windows host?

Comment: Can you provide the value of $PATH?

Comment: @DavidMaze - I have edited the post now to add the entrypoint.sh and yes the "shebang" has been added as you can see. I'm using MacBookPro so I believe the line endings should be Unix readable.

Comment: @mmoehrlein - the value of $PATH is - /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

Comment: Can you try making docker-entrypoint.sh executable? You can use ‘chmod +x FILENAME’

Comment: The Dockerfile is invalid, it's missing a FROM line.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before.  Not sure how to fix it.

BUT, luckily, there is a 2nd format you can write that command in, for example:

```
ENTRYPOINT docker-entrypoint.sh node $TEST_VAR1 $TEST_VAR2
```